# How to prevent the particular url to be save in history by window.history javascript method

Tags: javascript

I am creating the mobile app in which I used a pop up  posting a reply. For navigating back I used  windows.history.go(-1). But When It comes on pop up history, the navigation button start to invoke the pop up again and again. Mean the history for pop up cannot let the history to traverse back anymore. Is it possible if the history for pop up would not get saved.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just go back two pages?

```
window.history.go(-2)
```

Comment: this is what we are skipping the step to go back right? I need if we can prevent history to store.